# Array initialized dynamically not recognized later

Tags: java, arrays, initialization

I am dynamically initializing an array, reading its size from the file. The size of the array is within the first line of the input file. Thus the initialization is in the if block

Sample code

```
line="";
FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileName);
BufferedReader bf= new BufferedReader(fr);

int lineNo=0;
String firstLine="";
String[] mazeInfoStr;
int[] mazeInfo;
int[][] maze;
while((line=bf.readLine())!=null)
{
  if(lineNo==0)
  {
    firstLine=line;
    mazeInfoStr=line.split(" ");
    mazeInfo= new int[mazeInfoStr.length];
    for(int i=0;i<mazeInfoStr.length;i++)
    {
      mazeInfo[i]=Integer.parseInt(mazeInfoStr[i]);
    }
    maze=new int[mazeInfo[0]][mazeInfo[1]];
  }
  if(lineNo!=0 && lineNo<=mazeInfo[0]) //mazeInfo not initialized error here
  {
    int[] rookRow;
    String[] rookRowStr=line.split(" ");
    for(int i=0;i<rookRowStr.length;i++)
    {
      rookRow[i]=Integer.parseInt(rookRowStr[i]);
      maze[lineNo-1][i]=rookRow[i];
    }
  }
}
```

I am getting an error when I try to use the mazeInfo array later (also the same for the other arrays like rookRow, maze). I realize that the array is initialized in an if block but what should be done if it needs to be used later in the code outside of that if block?

Comment: Assign `null` to them or array of zero length in declaration.

Comment: What do you mean by "later"? Where is the code line that causes the error?

Comment: @FredK line which causes error is annotated with respective comment

Comment: `lineNo` is never incremented so it's always 0.

Comment: @Ivan, thank you. That works perfectly, I should have thought about that. Very helpful.

Comment: @Andrew S, yes I do increment it later, missed adding that code